# Why does Perl read only half of lines in file?

Tags: string, perl, file, split, line

I want to read a file line by line and for each line split the string and print it. But the script only prints the even lines.

File:

```
line1:item1
line2:item2
line3:item3
line4:item4
line5:item5
line6:item6
```

and the script:

```
$FILE = "file";
open($FILE, "<", "file") or die("Could not open file.");

while (<$FILE>) {
    my $number = (split ":", <$FILE>)[1];
    print $number;
}
```

output:

```
item2
item4
item6
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

This is because you read two lines per loop round

```
while (<$FILE>) { # read lines 1, 3, 5
    my $number = (split ":", <$FILE>)[1]; # read lines 2, 4, 6
    print $number;
}
```

use this instead

```
while (<$FILE>) {
    my $number = (split /:/)[1];
    print $number;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`<$FILE>` will read a line. You read one line in while, and another in split.

Answer (score 0):

Because you read 1 line in the while and another one when spliting.

Answer (score 0):

Small mistake.
You read one line in while and another in next immediate line(where you use split ).